# Making flashcards with "select" command

Tags: bash

So I have a file called "nouns" that looks like this:

```
English word:matching Spanish word 
Englsih word:matching Spanish word
..etc etc
```

I need to make a program that list all the English words with an option to quit. The program displays the English words and ask the user for the word he wants translated and he can also type "quit" to exit.

This is what I have so far that shows me the list in English

```
select english in $(cut -d: -f1 nouns)

do
if [ "$english" = 'quit' ]
then
exit 0
fi
done
```

I know that I need to run a command that pulls up the second column (-f2) by searching for the corresponding English word like this

```
result=$(grep -w $english nouns|cut -d: -f2)
```

My end result should just out put the corresponding Spanish word. I am just not sure how to get all the parts to fit together. I know its based in a type of "if" format (I think) but do I start a separate if statement for the grep line?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop in which you ask for input from user. The rest is putting things together with the correct control flow. See my code below:

```
while :
do 
  read -p "Enter word (or quit): " input

  if [ "$input" = "quit" ]; then
    echo "exiting ..."
    break
  else
    echo "searching..."
    result=$(grep $input nouns | cut -d ':' -f 2)
    if [[ $result ]]; then
      echo "$result"
    else
      echo "not found"
    fi
  fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to run this in a constant [`while` loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html), only [breaking the loop](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_05.html) if the user enters "quit." Get the input from the user [using `read`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_08_02.html) to put it in a variable. As for the searching, this can be done pretty easily with [`awk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/) (which is designed to work with delimited files like this) or [`grep`](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/).

```
#!/bin/sh
while true; do
    read -p "Enter english word: " word
    if [ "$word" = "quit" ]; then
        break
    fi

# Take your pick, either of these will work:
#    awk -F: -v "w=$word" '{if($1==w){print $2; exit}}' nouns
    grep -Pom1 "(?<=^$word:).*" nouns
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dfile=./dict

declare -A dict
while IFS=: read -r en es; do
    dict[$en]=$es
done < "$dfile"

PS3="Select word>"
select ans in "${!dict[@]}" "quit program"; do
case "$REPLY" in
    [0-9]*) w=$ans;;
    *) w=$REPLY;;
esac

case "$w" in
    quit*) exit 0;;
    *) echo "${dict[$w]}" ;;
esac

done
```